# How to draw mandala when I intend to color it with pencil colors?

Tags: drawing, colored-pencils, mandala

Mandala drawings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandala

Color pencils are not strong enough to hide the normal pencil. Example: Orange color pencil will not hide the underlying HB graphite pencil *outline*.

How to draw mandala when I intend to color it with pencil colors?

Comment: Is there a particular reason the outline needs to be hidden, or that you can't try it in a light colored pencil that hides easily?

Comment: You can try to use a 4H or 6H graphite pencil, the outline will be less visible, but it could be visible if you want to color with very light color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can only think of a few options.

1. Don't worry about masking or hiding the sketch. Make bold, dark outlines on purpose. Sketch the pattern you want in graphite, then draw the lines very dark (in graphite, or even ink). This does give the final result something of a "coloring book" feel, which may not be what you're wanting.
2. Sketch outlines in the color of their section, or in some very light color (e.g. yellow, pale blue), instead of with graphite. This requires more planning of what colors will go in what part of the pattern.
3. Draw the outlines dark and bold, and put a second sheet of paper over top to trace those dark lines in the lighter colors of the final drawing. This is easier if you have a light board, but still possible even on a tabletop with sufficiently thin paper.

Comment: 3 rd point.  Does that mean that final drawing should be on a thin paper?

Comment: Correct -- the bottom page (outlines) can be on any thickness paper, but the top page (final drawing) would need to be on a thin enough paper to be able to see the outlines. _Sometimes_ copy/printer paper is thin enough to trace through, depending on the darkness of the underlying drawing.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to do your drawing with a graphite pencil, but you need to take with an xH hardness grade where x refers to a number. The higher this number will be, the harder the writing core will be and thus the lighter the mark left on the paper will be.

You also need to pay attention how hard you press on the pencil, even if the pencil lead is soft. A light pressure is advised otherwise you will flatten the tooth of your paper, and you won't be able to color this part of your drawing.

Here is a comparison of strokes with different graphite pencils, depending on their graphite scale.

[image]